# Question about embedding in abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am new to abstract algebra, and I am confused about the essence of embedding. I have met similar dealing ways two times up to now. The first is we can embed $R$(a ring) into $R[X]$, the polynomial ring over it. The second one is we can embed $R$(a domain) into the $Frac(R)$, the fraction field of it. The tools for both scenarios are through an injective homomorphism. Some books even state that $R \subset R[X](R \subset Frac(R))$

> My question is how can we understand this since for instance, $R$ and $Frac(R)$ (the former is a set of elements, namely $a$, the latter is a set of equivalence classes, namely $\bar{\frac{r}{s}}$) are different.

Comment: It means that $Frac(R)$ contains a subring which is very naturally isomorphic to $R$. So if we identify an element $r\in R$ with $\frac{r}{1}$, we can say that $R\subseteq Frac(R)$. For example, we always think of $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ with that embedding. Similarly, we can identify elements of $R$ with constant polynomials in $R[x]$.

Comment: So the logic goes as $R$ is isomorphic to $f(R)$, where $f$ is an isomorphism and $f(R)$ is a subring of $Frac(R)$, so in essence, $f(R) \subset Frac(R)$. Why can we say $R \subset Frac(R)$? I think my question needs some insights about understanding isomorphism.

Comment: From my angle, isomorphism is weaker than equivalence, why sometimes deal with it as equivalence?

Comment: It is indeed not inclusion by definitions of set theory. But sometimes $R$ is so naturally isomorphic to $f(R)$ that it would be just too annoying to mention $f$ every time, and we can just identify $R$ with $f(R)$. Because if you think about it, none of the inclusions $\mathbb{N}\subseteq\mathbb{Z}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{R}\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ is a real inclusion. Every new set just contains a "natural copy" of the previous one. Yet we usually do think of these as inclusions. So $R\subseteq Frac(R)$ is a convenient notation, rather than a real inclusion.

Comment: I asked another question related to this and I use the annoying way to prove it. It seems it is very inconvenient. But I did not know how to get rid of the dirty part. Can you help me with it? URL = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4629454}